# Run executable file in linux - not working

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I am having trouble running an executable file in linux.

The path is: root/Downloads/eclipse_BIRT_Report_Designer

When double clicking on the file eclipse.exe I receive the following error:

> Archive:  /root/Downloads/eclipse_BIRT_Report_Designer/eclipse.exe
>   [/root/Downloads/eclipse_BIRT_Report_Designer/eclipse.exe]
>   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
>   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
>   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
>   the last disk(s) of this archive. note: 
>   /root/Downloads/eclipse_BIRT_Report_Designer/eclipse.exe may be a
>   plain executable, not an archive zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile
>   directory in one of
>   /root/Downloads/eclipse_BIRT_Report_Designer/eclipse.exe or
>             /root/Downloads/eclipse_BIRT_Report_Designer/eclipse.exe.zip, and
>   cannot find
>   /root/Downloads/eclipse_BIRT_Report_Designer/eclipse.exe.ZIP, period.

The foile is set as "allow executing file to run as program" in properties.

When using terminal command ./eclipse.exe I am presented with the following error:

> [root@localhost eclipse_BIRT_Report_Designer]# ./eclipse.exe bash:
>   ./eclipse.exe: cannot execute binary file

Any solutions? Please keep it simple as I am new to this.

Comment: Usually, `.exe` is only used for Windows executables. In order to run software on Linux, you will need Linux executables.

Comment: Did you download it from eclipse.org? There you have to go to "download packages", switch to Linux and download an .tar.gz-file. And do you really want to download BIRT-Report-Designer - not the pure Java-IDE?

Comment: thank you, problem solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have downloaded the wrong version that only works for windows. There is an all in one download option available which will work for linux at

http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/

And run the executable file.

Comment: thank you, took me a while to realise this - thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

Files with then ending `.exe` cannot be run within Linux without using wine